# MySQL update column which is a value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my previous question related to the my query.
[MySQL select column which is a value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681549/mysql-select-column-which-is-a-value-in-another-column)

The problem is that want to do operations on the values extracted and store it back into the original db. I've tried using a `update` & `case` but am not able to achieve it.

```
update msisdn_table
   CASE reason
     WHEN 'NoAnswer' THEN (case when (NoAnswer>0) then update msisdn_table set NoAnswer = NoAnswer-1 end)
     WHEN 'NetworkBusy' THEN (case when NetworkBusy>0 then update msisdn_table set NetworkBusy = NetworkBusy-1 end)
     WHEN 'CallRejection' THEN (case when CallRejection>0 then update msisdn_table set CallRejection = CallRejection-1 end)
     WHEN 'Unavailable' THEN (case when Unavailable>0 then update msisdn_table set Unavailable = Unavailable-1 end)
   END
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way if you want to do it one statement

```sql
UPDATE msisdn_table
   SET NoAnswer      = IFNULL(IF(reason = 'NoAnswer',      
                                 NULLIF(NoAnswer,      0) - 1, NoAnswer), 0), 
       NetworkBusy   = IFNULL(IF(reason = 'NetworkBusy',   
                                 NULLIF(NetworkBusy,   0) - 1, NetworkBusy), 0), 
       CallRejection = IFNULL(IF(reason = 'CallRejection', 
                                 NULLIF(CallRejection, 0) - 1, CallRejection), 0), 
       Unavailable   = IFNULL(IF(reason = 'Unavailable',   
                                 NULLIF(Unavailable,   0) - 1, Unavailable), 0)
  WHERE reason IN('NoAnswer', 'NetworkBusy', 'CallRejection', 'Unavailable');
```

**Note:**

1. I changed `CASE` with less verbose `IF()`, although if you like it better you can use it the same way.
2. This approach has one possible side effect as it always updates the column(s) either with a new or with old value. It may matter if for example you have a trigger defined on the table.
3. You want to apply a `WHERE` clause to make sure that rows with other `reason` codes are not affected

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60c30/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
update msisdn_table set  NoAnswer = NoAnswer-1 where (NoAnswer>0) ;
update msisdn_table set  NetworkBusy = NetworkBusy-1 where (NetworkBusy = NetworkBusy-1) ;
update msisdn_table set  CallRejection = CallRejection-1 where (CallRejection>0) ;
update msisdn_table set  'Unavailable' = 'Unavailable'-1 where (Unavailable>0) ;
```